# How to get the name of the image which is allocated in drawable folder?

Tags: android, string, image, sqlite

In my Android application, in SQLite db, I have a picture attribute of type String.

The following code works and allows me to retrieve image from drawable folder and display it in the ImageView.

```
protected ImageView pictureView;
...
pictureView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureView);
pictureView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.howard));
// howard.png is my image
```

The problem is that I can't get the images of my objects dynamically because my code for generating string that represents the name of the image in drawable doesn't seem to work.

I tried to do it these ways but it doesn't work.

1st way:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String picture = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("picture"));
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("samples.companydirectory.drawable/" + picture, null, null);
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(id);
pictureView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

2nd way:

```
pictureView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureView);
String picture = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("picture"));
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("samples.companydirectory.drawable/" + picture, null, null);
pictureView.setImageResource(id);
```

XML code:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pictureView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a class like so many things

```
public static int getResourceId(Context context, String name)
   {
       int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());       
       return resourceId;
   }
```

In your case is well

```
pictureView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureView);
String picture = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("picture"));
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(picture, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
pictureView.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: Remove `"drawable/"+` and it will work. The second parameter, indicating the type, will tell the function which is the path where to look in. It's `int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());`

Comment: the context of their activity is.

Comment: Context context = getApplicationContext();

Comment: Context context = this or simply 
getResourceId(this, picture)

Comment: the picture variable show what? 
make Lod.d("DEBUG", picture) after getString and check if the same that assets folder.

Comment: thanks for your help Igor, can u tell me what u have for android:src in ur xml?

Comment: do not need... android:src you already set in pictureView.setImageResource(id);

Comment: In my working example that I have at the very top of my question which uses setImageDrawable(), what can I use instead of hard coded 'howard' string. How do I dynamically generate that name for each different object?

Comment: change "R.drawable.howard for your new id that you get in getResourceId(this, picture)